# Вывод содержимого файла в textedit

Tags: linux, qtcreator

Нужно в qtcreator в линукс вывести все процессы в textedit. Я так понял, что для этого нужно открыть файл /bin/ps, но выбивает ошибку.
no matching function for call to ‘QTextEdit::append(QFile&)’
 ui->textEdit->append(file);
                          ^
Как правильно считать содержимое файла ?

```
}
    QFile file("/bin/ps");
    file.isOpen();
    ui->textEdit->append(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 QFile file("/bin/ps");
 if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
 {
    QString temp(file.ReadAll());
    ui -> textEdit -> append(temp);
 }
```

Comment: ошибка: no matching function for call to ‘QFile::isOpen(QIODevice::OpenModeFlag)’
     if (file.isOpen(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
                                        ^

Comment: Вместо file.IsOpen используйте file.open

Comment: Я немного перепутал. ps - это же, как я понимаю, все процессы в линуксе. Мне надо все эти процессы вывести в textedit. В консоль оно нормально выводит, а в textedit ошибка, что нельзя из int конвертировать в стринг.

Comment: Все верно. ps - это не отдельный текстовой файл, а утилита.
Чтобы получить файл со списком процессов, нужно воспользоваться такой командой:

 /bin/bash -c "/bin/ps aux > /path/to/output/file"

Comment: Так же вы можете воспользоваться решением, предоставленным на этом ресурсе: http://askubuntu.com/questions/522640/how-to-make-bin-ps-called-with-aux-as-its-argument-write-to-a-file

Comment: Мне для курсовой нужно. Там всё проще должно быть :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47161/discussion-between--and-aquinary).